# How to set up point system for personality quiz in javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, radio-button, points

Fairly new to javascript, I'm doing a personality quiz, so theres multiple endings.

I know to set up an array for my variables and an array to store user input, I've got the buttons set up radio style.

Now the question is how does one go about setting up a point system based on user input that will display a specific answer at the end?  I just need some help being steered in the right direction! Thank you!  Also do I have to use eventListeners for the radio buttons?

Comment: Show us some code you already have ("show us" means add it to your question, that's what [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32670008/edit) is for). We will not code it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple and NO you do not need event listeners:

All you do is set a value to the radios and as they select them keep a tally

**HTML:**

```
<question>
    <h3>Are you smart?</h3>
    <p>
      <label>
        <input type='radio' name="smarts" value="20" />
        <span class="checkable">Yes</span>
      </label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input id="radiodemo2" checked type='radio' name="smarts" value="10" />
      <label for="radiodemo2" class="checkable">No</span>
    </p>
  </question>
```

**JS:**

```
var quiz = {}

 quiz.view = function(state, props) {

  state.$looks = state.$smarts = {
    _onclick: function(event) {
      props.totals[this.name] = parseInt(this.value)
    }
  }

  state.results = props.totals.smarts + props.totals.looks
}

var props = {
  totals: {
    smarts: 0,
    looks: 0
  }
}

mag.module("quiz", quiz, props)
```

Here is the full working example: http://jsbin.com/xuzavunaci/2/edit?js,output

Hope that helps!